# Migrate java class to Kotlin - Cannot resolve symbol annotate class

Tags: kotlin, android-annotations

Android Studio 3.4.2

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

in app/build.gradle:

```
    def AAVersion = '4.6.0'
def KOTLIN_COROUTINE_VERSION = '1.2.1'

    dependencies {
        annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"

        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
        implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0@aar') { transitive = true; }
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
        implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$KOTLIN_COROUTINE_VERSION"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$KOTLIN_COROUTINE_VERSION"

    }
```

I has activity (**java class**) annotate by `org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity`

Here snippet:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity

@EActivity
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

}
```

And another java activity (**SplashActivity.java**) that call this `LoginActivity` like this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity

@EActivity
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {


Intent intent = new Intent(thisActivity, LoginActivity_.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Nice it's work fine.

Now I migrate only **LoginActivity** to Kotlin class (`LoginActivity.kt`)

like this:

```
import org.androidannotations.annotations.Background
import org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity

@EActivity
open class LoginActivity : Activity() {

}
```

and now **SplashActivity.java** has compile error in this line:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(thisActivity, LoginActivity_.class);
```

error message:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'LoginActivity_'
```

P.S. If I remove "_" than compile success:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(thisActivity, LoginActivity.class);
```

But I need to use `LoginActivity_`

Comment: should it have or have not that "_" symbol after the name. `LoginActivity` or `LoginActivity_`

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher I update my post

Comment: then rename it to `LoginActivity_` where is the problem

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher Class "LoginActivity_" is generate class. It's generate by annotation lib

Comment: you should call the `LoginActivity_` after you perform build. And how can you be sure if that's generated. Is that a library or is that a personal library you are developing

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher I rebuild my project, but it's not help

Answer (score 1):

You have to [use `kapt`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html#using-in-gradle) instead of `annotationProcessor` to handle Kotlin files. Any annotation processor may or may not correctly handle them; for `androidannotations` in particular [there is documentation on Kotlin support](https://github.com/androidannotations/androidannotations/wiki/Kotlin-support).